# Multiple and varying BSOD's at seemingly random times

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, ssd, bsod

**The problem(s)**

Hello, I have finally become so flustered with trying to resolve these issues on my own and am seeking help with these random BSOD's. For reference, my system specs are:

OS: windows 10
Video card: NVIDIA gtx 760 (4GB GDDR5)
motherboard: gigabyte 970-A
CPU: AMD-6350
RAM: hyperX Fury 16GB 1600MHz DDR3
SSD: ADATA 128GB

In short, I will frequently and randomly receive BSOD's whilst doing anything from browsing the internet to gaming. The most frequent ones i get are "IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL" and "attempt to write on read-only memory", though i have gotten a variety of different ones as well. Every time these occur, my system temperatures are optimal. The only one that i could seemingly trace a cause for was while i was transferring a large file from my SSD to my HDD. Every single time, i would get a freeze during this process, forcing a restart. It should be noted that disk activity was around 60-70% during this.

**DMP**

Here is a link to the image of my latest DMP caused by a BSOD while gaming:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5fK9.png

https://www.dropbox.com/s/61f4bjoywd41d8z/DUMP.zip?dl=0

Please, if you need any other information that i might be missing, please do not hesitate to ask me a question!

Comment: share the real dmp file and not the picture

Comment: Could you perhaps point me in the direction to do so? I am not very good at this stuff. @magicandre1981

Comment: copy the folder C:\windows\minidump to the desktop, zip the folder and upload the zip (onedrive, dropbox) and post the share link here

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/61f4bjoywd41d8z/DUMP.zip?dl=0 @magicandre1981

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Looking at the dmp with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that you get a memory corruption while Windows tries to rearrange the Standby List (Superfetch Cache):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

ATTEMPTED_WRITE_TO_READONLY_MEMORY (be)
An attempt was made to write to readonly memory.  The guilty driver is on the
stack trace (and is typically the current instruction pointer).
When possible, the guilty driver's name (Unicode string) is printed on
the bugcheck screen and saved in KiBugCheckDriver.


STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault
02 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
03 nt!KiPageFault
04 nt!MiUnlinkNumaStandbyPage
05 nt!MiRemoveLowestPriorityStandbyPage
06 nt!MiPruneStandbyPages
07 nt!MiRebalanceZeroFreeLists
08 nt!ExpWorkerThread
09 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
0a nt!KiStartSystemThread

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xBE_nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault

BUCKET_ID:  0xBE_nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xBE_nt!MiRaisedIrqlFault
```

This looks like a RAM issue. Test each RAM module on its own (remove the other ones from the PC) with [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso) for errors. Also run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and make sure the RAM timings in memory and SPD tab match. If you see a Command Rate of 1(T), change this to 2 in BIOS.

Comment: Thank you! I have installed CPU-Z and get no command rate readings for memory or SPD tabs. The memtest will unfortunately have to wait until tomorrow, but i will post the results of that. @magicandre1981

Comment: Okay, so i ran the memtest on each stick and found no errors. However, i did find that because of the cpu heatsink/fan block, i had previously had the RAM modules in slots 0 and 1 instead of 0 and 2 ( alternating ). Could this be the source of the issue @magicandre1981

Comment: also RAM slots on the motherboard can be damaged and cause corruptions.

Comment: Now i find that i just get freezing with audio stutters requiring a shut down ( via the power button ). These occur during gaming and usually watching videos online. These occur without BSOD's. @magicandre1981

Comment: check for the command rate values in CPU-Z

Comment: There are still no command rate values show in CPU-Z ( its all greyed out boxes).

Comment: make pictures of all CPU-Z tabs and post them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51888/discussion-between-gavsta707-and-magicandre1981).